# No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - Spree Fancy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I am making a spree app and following along on their github, and their website. I wanted to see 'spree fancy', so I installed it and followed the directions on their github page. When I ran `bundle exec rails g spree_fancy:install`, I got the error;

`/Users/me/my-project/vendor/bundle/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/actions/inject_into_file.rb:98:in`binread'`: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen -                  /Users/me/myproject/vendor/assets/javascripts/spree/frontend/all.js (Errno::ENOENT)`

Here is what my Gemfile looks like

**Gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby '2.1.3'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.1.8'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

gem 'spree', '2.4.0'
gem 'spree_gateway', github: 'spree/spree_gateway', branch: '2-4-stable'
gem 'spree_auth_devise', github: 'spree/spree_auth_devise', branch: '2-4-stable'
gem 'spree_fancy', :github => 'spree/spree_fancy', branch: '2-2-stable'
```

I've followed what the Spree Docs have said to do, and it hasnt been working for me. I could try a different version of spree if that means it would work, but I'm not sure which version would work with spree fancy.

I also followed the spree github guide, which said to use the new version of rails. I installed with `rails 4.2.0` but it didnt work with the spree gem, so I went back to `rails 4.1.8`.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems, that Spree version (2.4.0) does not contain frontend/all.js(css) files.
https://github.com/spree/spree/tree/2-4-stable/frontend/app/assets/javascripts/spree/frontend
https://github.com/spree/spree/tree/2-4-stable/frontend/app/assets/stylesheets/spree/frontend

It seems using frontend.js(css) should do work:

```
# app/assets/javascripts/application.js
//= require 'frontend'
```

and

```
# app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
/*= require 'frontend' */
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I was able to get it fixed by downgrading to `gem 'spree', :github => 'spree/spree', :branch => '2-3-stable'` and made everything including `spree fancy` 2.3 and it seems to work. Not sure why it doesnt work on the stable branch.